# ¿Cómo centrar un enlace html al pie de página?

Tags: html

Quiero añadir la política de privacidad a mi web pero al añadir el enlace en html y guardar aparece muy pegado a la esquina izquierda.

```
<a href="aquí va mi enlace" >Política de Privacidad</a>
```

¿Y cómo sería para que se abriese la página en una ventana nueva?

Desde ya muchas gracias :)

Comment: Aunque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, esa solución no centra el enlace, sólo lo está desplazando hacia la izquierda. Hay muchas maneras de centrar un elemento de texto, la más cómoda sería aplicar `display: block` y  `text-align: center` al enlace

Comment: ¿Podrías hacerme el código para probar? <a href="aquí va mi enlace" >Política de Privacidad</a>

Comment: `<a href="aquí va mi enlace" style="text-align: center; display: block;">Política de Privacidad</a>` Teniendo en cuenta que sea solo texto y no esté contenido dentro de otro elemento con otras características que no nos estés mostrando

Comment: Muchas gracias. Acabo de probar y me viene mucho mejor centrarlo yo mismo poniendo el valor en px deseado. Cambiando de tema, ¿habría alguna forma para hacer que "Política de Privacidad" apareciese solo al pie de la página de inicio y no en las entradas? Saludos :)

Comment: Tal como está tu pregunta no podría responderte por aquí, podrías abrir una nueva aportando más información, si es HTML estático bastaría con borrar esa línea de tus entradas, si estás llamando esos elementos, por ejemplo con un include de PHP o scripts en JS, ya seria diferente la solución

Comment: ¿Pero habría que eliminar de cada entrada el mensaje/enlace? ¿No se puede añadir solamente al pie de página y que cada vez que crees una nueva entrada no aparezca?

Comment: Te repito, con la información en tu pregunta no podría saber cómo estás creando tu página, si lo que quieres es automatizar un poco este proceso, podrías usar archivos php (uno para entradas y otro para inicio) e incluirlos sólo en dónde quieras que estén. Documéntate sobre "include & require php" si necesitas más información al respecto. O abre otra pregunta y aporta más información de lo que tienes

Comment: O si de paso no quieres cambiar a PHP, puedes incluir archivos externos con JavaScript, ¿cómo? Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, cada quien te recomendará una basado en su experiencia y la forma de tu proyecto, documéntate bien sobre cómo incluir scripts de JS en tu proyecto y nos cuentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
<a href="aquí va mi enlace" target="_blank" style="margin-left:10px;" >Política de Privacidad</a>
```

target="_blank" Te permite abrir en una nueva página

margin-left:10px Te permite dar margen izquierdo.

No olvides valorar la respuesta, espero te sirva.

Comment: Vale hacer el hincapié de evitar los estilos inline si es possible :)

Comment: Vale, está genial. ¡Muchas gracias! Otra cosa... ¿cómo tendría que poner para dejar un pequeño espacio en blanco entre "Política de Privacidad" y el pie de la web? Está muy pegado.

Comment: Puedes utilizar margenes, margin-botton:10px similar al margin-left, no olvides marcar como mejor respuesta, si te sirvió.

Comment: Talvez en este caso seria mejor utilizar `padding` en vez de `margin`, ya que el segundo (dependiendo de como hayas contruido el sitio) puede causar un espacio vacio visible

Comment: Ivan tiene razón, puedes utilizar padding

Comment: ¿Esto se haría con CSS?

Comment: exacto lo puedes colocar en una hoja de estilo o en el misma etiqueta <a>: style="paddin-bottom:10px;"

Comment: ¿Sería entonces en el mismo sitio? <a href="aquí va mi enlace" target="_blank" style="margin-left:10px;" >Política de Privacidad</a> <a>: style="paddin-bottom:10px;"

Comment: No, sería así: <a href="aquí va mi enlace" target="_blank" style="margin-left:10px; paddin-bottom:10px;" >Política de Privacidad</a>

Comment: Dentro del atributo style puedes agregar todas los estilos que desees

Comment: Aunque como puedes ver la etiqueta se vuelve bastante larga y dificil de leer, por lo que es mejor aplicar los estilos en un archivo aparte y referenciarlos por una clase aplicada en tu etiqueta, asi como: `<a href="aquí va mi enlace" class="tu_clase" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>`

Comment: Sí, llevas razón. Parece que paddin-bottom:10px;" no funciona. Da igual que valor le ponga sustituyendo al 10...

Comment: Prueba con margin o podrías colocar la etiqueta a dentro de un div y en el div aplicar el estilo.

Comment: De acuerdo, miraré a ver. ¡Muchas gracias a tod@s!